# Closed form solutions of 2D p-laplace equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

While investigating a physics problem, I found the following PDE:

$\vec\nabla. (|\vec\nabla  P|^p \vec \nabla P) = 0 $

Where $\vec\nabla =(\dfrac{\partial }{\partial r},\dfrac {1}{r}  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta}) $, i.e, this is a two dimensional problem.

When $p = 0$, I end up with laplace equation and I can solve without problems.
When $p > 0$, I can find solutions that depend only on r. These, however, doesn't work for what I want.

So, to the point: can I find some kind of solution "similar" to the ones I find when $p=0$? I think the answer is probably not, because the equation is not linear... However, can I find some kind of pertubative solution when p is near 0? When I try this I end up with a more awkward equation...
All the papers I read about this are too technical and they don't talk about closed form solutions to this equation.